# different keyboards have different layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, intellij

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop and since installation I have some strange problems with layout.

Firstly, the default setting for changing layout is not working, it just changes the indicator, so that it states for "En", when really layout is russian. When I manually change language with this indicator, this also have no effect with layouts.

This problem seems to be solved with just running `setxkbmap` after logging in:

```
$ setxkbmap -option "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:ralt" -layout us,ru
```

So I mentioned this problem just as I think, it can be linked with the real one.

Secondly, when I attach my laptop to the external keyboard, I have different layouts on these keyboards: if I push the same button on different keyboards, I have different symbols.

And finally and most annoying, when I use IntelliJ IDEA, I can't use any shortcuts, containing letters. And that applies only to internal keyboard. Of course, I tried changing layout multiple times.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You should really split this into three separate questions.

Comment: @gioele you don't think, they're linked?

Comment: Probably not. Ask separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't mind the first problem, I may get rid of the second and the third: just turning off any Gnome-based layout features (set one language) and use just `setxkbmap`.

So, the final solution would be:

1. Turn off embedded solutions for layout switching and set only one input language (English).
2. add `setxkbmap -option "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:ralt" -layout us,ru` entry to `Menu -> Startup Applications`